# Bash ignores Quotes in command line arguments

Tags: bash, scripting

Got some odd behaviour coming out of a bash script

myscript.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
# Demo bash script
for i in $@
do
   echo $i
done
echo $# args
```

if I execute it thus:

```
myscript.sh "Arg 1" "Arg 2"
```

Result:

```
Arg
1
Arg
2
2 args
```

So it's calculating the correct number of args but processing them wrong or more to the point **I'm processing them wrong**

Any thoughts?

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net and it'll identify this and other issues automatically.

Comment: BTW, same thing applies to the `echo`, which should use `"$i"`; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else), and [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`for i in $@`

to

`for i in "$@"`

in order to apply correctly parameter expansion.

Comment: Duplicates should be flagged, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of How to Answer.